# reading csv file and writing to another file using python

Tags: python, csv

Hi I am new to python and I want to write a program which will read the csv file and write the data to another file.

Below is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import csv

FEED_FILE = '/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754/20170529_MUREX_EOD_REC_RATES_20170531.csv'
OUT_FILE = '/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754/20170529_MUREX_EOD_REC_RATES_20170531_out.csv'

with open(OUT_FILE, 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
    with open(FEED_FILE, newline='') as feed:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reader = csv.reader(feed, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader: 
        row[3] = sorted(list(row[3].split(','))
                writer.writerow(row)
```

but I am getting below error, which I am not able to understand why?

```
$./Csvreader.py
  File "./Csvreader.py", line 14
    writer.writerow(row)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me with the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the indentation.

Comment: check the parentheses on the previous line. you forgot to close `sorted(...`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
with open(OUT_FILE, 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
    with open(FEED_FILE, newline='') as feed:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reader = csv.reader(feed, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader: 
            row[3] = sorted(list(row[3].split(',')))
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the indentation!

```
with open(OUT_FILE, 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
    with open(FEED_FILE, newline='') as feed:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reader = csv.reader(feed, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader: 
            row[3] = sorted(list(row[3].split(','))
            writer.writerow(row)
```

EDIT:
For your updated question, there is an indentation problem again!

this

```
           row[3] = sorted(list(row[3].split(','))
                writer.writerow(row)
```

should be

```
                row[3] = sorted(list(row[3].split(','))
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: A different error would have been thrown in that case. If you look, the `sorted` call on the previous line is missing the closing parenthesis

Comment: Thanks for your response .. even this code is also giving the same error